# Mysql regexp easy

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to get all lines that according to the pattern 
xxx.xxx  (only)
where x is a number from 1 to 9 or any letter

My expression does not work `REGEXP  '[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}'`

Thx!

UPD: Thx fo all, but does not work!
I tryed so

```
SELECT email, registered, voted, ip, agent
FROM  `voters` 
WHERE member =199
AND DATE_FORMAT( voted,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <  '2014-09-23'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX( email,  '@', 1 ) 
REGEXP  '[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}'
```

result:

```
libsherbakul@...
savelkina_061080@...
dreik_339@...
simauta25@....
suslenkovagtp@...
driamoff@...
anashkina_1966@...
fedotovauliya@...
omsklib@...
```

UPD 2: Itryed change pattern so  `'[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}[\.]{1}[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}'`
RESULT:

```
regina.zheyli@...
rus.antonin@...
kira.albenina@...
alya.oktya@...
andryushka.gromov.1986@...
inna.festival@...
ilyubaj.baktybaev@...
vika.korotkova.02@...
silina.lika@...
mika.sidorova@...
kharlov.dmitriy@...
toni.gordon.70@...
vasya.ganichev.74@...
fomin.slavick22@...
```

No good, becouse more than 3 symbols before and after "."

Comment: try `[a-zA-Z1-9]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z1-9]{3,}`

Comment: does not work, passes over 3 symbols and few "."

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly three letters or digits followed by a dot, followed by exactly three characters with the same conditions and not more before and after then you've got to use

```
REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}$'
```

The special characters `^` and `$` have this meaning:

```
character     meaning
----------------------------------------------
    ^         Match the beginning of a string.
    $         Match the end of a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

`[a-z]` matches only lowercase alphabet. You need to specify uppercase, digits 1-9 too.

And the quantifier should be modified. `{1-3}` matches 1 to 3 times of preceding pattern. Use `{3}` to match 3 times.

```
REGEXP  '[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}
```

to allow 3 **only** on both sides of period.

and any letter as you said.